# querySelectorAll not working for specified elements

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I'm trying to achieve to select all specified elements that i want using looped `querySelectorAll` but I'm still failing. Only the first element is always selected. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="text">Text 1</div>
<div id="text">Text 2</div>
<div id="text">Text 3</div>
```

JS:

```
function query(selector) {
    var elem = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    if(elem.length) {
        for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
            return elem[i];
        }
    }
}

query("#text").style.background = "red";
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: what do you expect? your returning the first item from the collection also IDs must be unique.

Comment: @DanielA.White `querySelectorAll` does select all elements he provided, despite having non-unique IDs.

Comment: Do you intend to tweak the styles only or are you looking for a universal chainable solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return` statement terminates the function execution, i.e. the subsequent code is not executed. Your function returns the first selected element in the first iteration of the loop and that's the end of it.

In this case there is no need to iterate the collection. If you want to get all the selected elements you can return the returned value of the `querySelectorAll` method, but then you can't use the `style` property that way as the returned collection doesn't have such property.

```
function query(selector) {
    // convert the NodeList into a regular array
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}

// since `query` returns an array you can use it's `forEach` method 
// for iterating over the array
query(".text").forEach(function(el) {
   el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

Note that IDs must be unique. You should use classes instead.

Comment: While it's true that IDs should be unique, `querySelectorAll` does fetch all duplicate ID matches.

Comment: This is the best way to go with vanilla javascript

Comment: @squint Yes, that's true. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `return` statement, which only returns **first element** and then applies the chain to it. After that it is finished and no more elements get processed.

---

You can use this hack and have a truly **universal applicator**.

```
function query(selector, callback) {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), callback)
}
```

And this is how to use it.

```
query('#option', function(el){el.style.backgroundColor = "red"})
// or ES6
query('#option', el => el.style.backgroundColor = "blue")
```

Apply several changes at once:

```
query('#option', el => {
  el.style.backgroundColor = "green"
  el.style.color = 'cyan'
  el.style.textDecoration = 'line-through'
})
```

---

Or **mimick chaining**, if you want to be nasty for whatever reason...

```
function query(selector, callback) {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), callback) 

  return arguments.callee.bind(undefined, selector)
}
```

usage:

```
query('#option', el => el.style.backgroundColor = 'red')(el => el.style.color = 'black')(el => el.style.textDecoration = 'underline')
```

Comment: Nice! However you can skip the `.slice()` and the anonymous function and just do `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), callback)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` instead of `id` -- Ids have to be unique, but classes can be assigned to as many element as you want and you can assign as many classes to each element as well, so

```
<div class="mytext">Text 1</div>
<div class="mytext">Text 2</div>
<div class="mytext">Text 3</div>
```

And I suggest you use Jquery instead, so you can  do the background color as

```
$(".mytext").css({background:"red"});
```

Comment: The issue in the question has nothing to do with the IDs not being unique, and jQuery is just unnecessary.